# How to exclude consecutive values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d%H%M')
a = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\Nova pasta\TU_boia0401.out', parse_dates = ['data'], index_col = 0, date_parser = dateparse)
```

The output is something like this:

```
index               hs
2015-02-23 14:50:00 0.99
2015-02-23 15:50:00 0.96
2015-02-23 16:50:00 1.04
2015-02-23 17:50:00 0.96
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
2017-09-01 12:40:00 1.25
```

Till here everything was fine, but analysing all data by plotting it something was noticed. This is the problem:

[image]

As can be seeable near of 2015-03-06 there's a lot of repeated values that should not exist. Looking on dataframe this can be seeable:

```
2015-03-04 10:50:00 1.18
2015-03-04 11:50:00 1.18
2015-03-04 12:50:00 1.18
2015-03-04 13:50:00 1.18
```

It repeats a lot of times along of the dataframe. The main objective is to filter these BAD data and erase them from the dataframe and set np.nan to every value that repeats 3 consecutive times (or more than 3 too) to the entire dataframe. The output expectation is something like this:

```
index               hs
2015-02-23 14:50:00 0.99
2015-02-23 15:50:00 0.96
2015-02-23 16:50:00 1.04
2015-02-23 17:50:00 0.96
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
2015-03-04 10:50:00 1.18
2015-03-04 11:50:00 nan
2015-03-04 12:50:00 nan
2015-03-04 13:50:00 nan
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
2016-01-20 12:40:00 0.98
2016-01-20 12:50:00 nan
2016-01-20 13:00:00 nan
2016-01-20 13:10:00 nan
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
2017-09-01 12:40:00 1.25
```

Would be thankful if someone could help.

Comment: but drop_duplicates would drop then and I want to set np.nan if this reapets 3 or more times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets to NaN all forward duplicates greater than or equal to `n` (e.g. 3).

```
# Set-up.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 1), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-01-01', freq='min', periods=10), columns=['hs'])
df.loc[3:6] = df.iat[2, 0]
df.loc[8:10] = df.iat[7, 0]

>>> df
                           hs
2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.764052
2017-01-01 00:01:00  0.400157
2017-01-01 00:02:00  0.978738
2017-01-01 00:03:00  0.978738  # Duplicate x3
2017-01-01 00:04:00  0.978738  # Duplicate x3
2017-01-01 00:05:00  0.978738  # Duplicate x3
2017-01-01 00:06:00  0.950088
2017-01-01 00:07:00 -0.151357
2017-01-01 00:08:00 -0.151357  # Duplicate x2
2017-01-01 00:09:00 -0.151357  # Duplicate x2

# Set forward duplicates to NaN.
n = 3
bool_mask = df.hs.shift() == df.hs
df = df.assign(
    mask=bool_mask,
    group=(bool_mask != bool_mask.shift()).cumsum())
filter_groups = df.groupby('group')[['mask']].sum().query('mask >= {}'.format(n)).index
df.loc[df.group.isin(filter_groups), 'hs'] = np.nan
df = df[['hs']]
>>> df
                           hs
2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.764052
2017-01-01 00:01:00  0.400157
2017-01-01 00:02:00  0.978738
2017-01-01 00:03:00       NaN
2017-01-01 00:04:00       NaN
2017-01-01 00:05:00       NaN
2017-01-01 00:06:00  0.950088
2017-01-01 00:07:00 -0.151357
2017-01-01 00:08:00 -0.151357
2017-01-01 00:09:00 -0.151357
```

It creates a boolean mask to check for duplicates and adds this column to the dataframe via `assign`.  The code also adds a `group` column that looks for consecutive duplicate regions (created using the *shift-cumsum* pattern).  A groupby is applied to the groups, summing the `mask` boolean values.  This gives the number of consecutive repeats.  These results are then filtered using `query` to locate those where the repeat count is greater than or equal to `n` (e.g. 3).

Finally, the dataframe uses `loc` to set `hs` to `NaN` for the groups where the consecutive count exceeds three.  The temp columns are excluded by just taking `hs` from the dataframe via `df = df[['hs']]`.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**
Borrowing @Alexander's dataframe

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(10, 1),
    pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-01-01', freq='min', periods=10),
    ['hs'])

df.loc[4:6] = df.iat[3, 0]
```

**Solution**
Using [**`pd.DataFrame.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [**`pd.DataFrame.diff`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)
**Note:** This is a generalized solution that performs this same task for all columns at once.

```
df.mask(df.diff() == 0)

                           hs
2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.764052
2017-01-01 00:01:00  0.400157
2017-01-01 00:02:00  0.978738
2017-01-01 00:03:00  2.240893
2017-01-01 00:04:00       NaN
2017-01-01 00:05:00       NaN
2017-01-01 00:06:00  0.950088
2017-01-01 00:07:00 -0.151357
2017-01-01 00:08:00 -0.103219
2017-01-01 00:09:00  0.410599
```

---

Larger Example

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 5)).astype(float),
    pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-01-01', freq='min', periods=10),
).add_prefix('col')

df

                     col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
2017-01-01 00:00:00   0.0   3.0   2.0   3.0   2.0
2017-01-01 00:01:00   2.0   3.0   2.0   3.0   0.0
2017-01-01 00:02:00   2.0   0.0   0.0   4.0   0.0
2017-01-01 00:03:00   2.0   2.0   0.0   4.0   1.0
2017-01-01 00:04:00   3.0   2.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
2017-01-01 00:05:00   4.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   4.0
2017-01-01 00:06:00   3.0   1.0   3.0   0.0   4.0
2017-01-01 00:07:00   4.0   2.0   2.0   0.0   2.0
2017-01-01 00:08:00   4.0   0.0   4.0   1.0   4.0
2017-01-01 00:09:00   4.0   2.0   2.0   0.0   2.0
```

---

```
df.mask(df.diff() == 0)

                     col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
2017-01-01 00:00:00   0.0   3.0   2.0   3.0   2.0
2017-01-01 00:01:00   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.0
2017-01-01 00:02:00   NaN   0.0   0.0   4.0   NaN
2017-01-01 00:03:00   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN   1.0
2017-01-01 00:04:00   3.0   NaN   4.0   NaN   4.0
2017-01-01 00:05:00   4.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
2017-01-01 00:06:00   3.0   1.0   NaN   0.0   NaN
2017-01-01 00:07:00   4.0   2.0   2.0   NaN   2.0
2017-01-01 00:08:00   NaN   0.0   4.0   1.0   4.0
2017-01-01 00:09:00   NaN   2.0   2.0   0.0   2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the window size, you can use the rolling object. The idea is that if n successive elements are the same, their standard deviation will be 0. The rest is

```
successive = (ser.where(np.isclose(ser.rolling(3).std(), 0, atol=10**-6))
                 .bfill(limit=2).notnull())
ser[successive] = np.nan
```

For Series, `ser`

```
ser = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

this yields

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    1.0
13    2.0
14    1.0
15    3.0
16    2.0
17    NaN
18    NaN
19    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a for loop that keeps track of how many times something has been repeated:

```
replacement_value = np.nan
last_value = None
number_of_repetitions = 0
for index in range(len(values)):
   if value == last_value:
       if number_of_repetitions == 2: 
       #if we previously had 2 repetitions, we should replace both the current and the previous values
          values[index-1] = replacement_value
          values[index] = replacement_value
       if number_of_repetitions == 3: 
          #if this is the third or more repetition, we've already replaced the previous value, so we just need to handle the current one
          values[index] = replacement_value
       else:
          number_of_repetitions = number_of_repetitions+1
          #if it hasn't reach 3 yet, we should increment every time we see a repetition
          #but we don't need to keep track after 3      
   else: 
      #if this is a new value, we should reset
      number_of_repetitions = 1 
      last_value = value
```